# Rails - how to set default on edit form for a year select form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my app, I let people select their start year for a job. This works fine when creating a new job, but on the edit form I want the year the user selected during create to be automatically population.

My code:

```
<%= select_year Date.today, start_year: Time.now.year, end_year: Time.now.year - 95, field_name: :start, prefix: :job %>
```

Currently, it just defaults to 2013 everytime. I know I am passing in the instance variable correctly because the other fields are populated automatically, just not this year dropdown.

How do I get this to work?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your question. `start_year` is currently set to `Time.now.year`, which will output 2013 in the example above. If you want to pass in an instance variable, you can do so by changing `Time.now.year` to `@starting_year_instance_variable`.

Comment: I think I understand you, but my issue is that end_year depends on start year. So if I set start year to 2009 for example, I lose the options in the edit form for 2010, 2011, etc. How could I keep all the options and still select the year passed in from the controller for the edit view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer was too long to put in the comments, so I'm putting it here as an answer, but let me know if it answers your question or not.

You could manually set the `start_year` and `end_year` variables to, for example, 1950 and `Time.now.year`. Then, set the first argument in `select_year` helper to the instance variable to make it the default selection between the wide range instead of `Date.today`.

For example:

`<%= select_year @instance_variable, start_year: 1950, end_year: Time.now.year, field_name: :start, prefix: :job %>`

More examples are available in the Rails Docs, too:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-select_year